# How to display the output after finishing entering the inputs?

Tags: java

> here iam trying to get the factorial of N of numbers entered by the user , the problem is I want to display the output after entering all of the inputs,
> my code here display the output like this:

> 2  "N of numbers"

> 5 "first input"

> 120 "output of first input"

> 3 "second input"

> 6  "output of second input"

> and I want it to be like this:

> 2  "N of numbers"

> 5  "first input"

> 3  "second input"

> 120 " output of first"

> 6   "output of second"

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        int N = in.nextInt();
       
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
              int F = 1;
            int num = in.nextInt();
           
           
           

            for (int j = num; j > 0; j--) {

                F = F * j;
               
             
          
                     }
                     System.out.println(F);
            } 
                 
         
           
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: 1. Instead of printing your outputs in the loop, save them in some data structure that  can hold multiple values (a List or an Array for example). 2. Once your loop is finished iterate over that data structure and print all values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to save the inputs to an array or list, and then loop over it and print all the results once the input is done. E.g.:

```java
int[] inputs = new int[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    inputs[i] = in.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int F = 1;
    for (int j = inputs[i]; j > 0; j--) {
        F = F * j;
    }
    System.out.println(input[i] + "! = " + F);
}
```